# WCF and WSE 2.0 web services

Tags: wcf, wse

How I can use WCF to communicate to old school WSE 2.0 web services?

Comment: You may want to elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in my opinion, both WSE 2.0 and WSE 3.0 are obsolete, not "old school".

Second, you "just do it". Add a service reference and call through the proxy class. If everything is configured properly, it should just work. The exception would be if the old WSE code did something non standard. That is, if it did something that did not become part of the standard, but was supported in WSE.

Comment: Is this true?  Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650778.aspx it states that WCF and WSE 3.0 interoperate, however "WSE 3.0-enabled applications do not interoperate with WSE 2.0-enabled applications".   It doesn't explicitly cover WCF -> WSE 2.0 but I assume that is covered by the combination of the previous statements

Comment: Is what true? WSE 2.0 code is likely to not work with WCF to the extent it uses parts of the pre-standard that did not get into the standard.